# Error messge using selenium method 'isTextPresent'

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to search for a string on some site using Selenium (2.32) method "isTextPresent".
I order to do it efficently I need to search it case insensitive as suggested with regexpi but I get an error as following (HTML contains the string "WHAT YOU SAY"):

Declaration:

```
private Selenium selenium;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://openurl.ebscohost.com";
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
```

Option 1 ("'SAY' in uppercase"):

```
if(selenium.isTextPresent("WHAT YOU SAY")) {
    return ("PASS");
}
else{ return "FAIL";}
```

Output: "PASS"

Option 2 ("'SAy' with lower case leter"):

```
if(selenium.isTextPresent("WHAT YOU SAy")) {
    return ("PASS");
}
else{ return "FAIL";}
```

Output: "FAIL"

Option 3 ("'SAy' with lower case letter but with regexp"):

```
if(selenium.isTextPresent("regexp:WHAT YOU SAy")) {
    return ("PASS");
}
else{ return "FAIL";}
```

Output: "FAIL"

Option 4 ("'Say' with lower case letter but with regexpi"):

```
if(selenium.isTextPresent("regexpi:WHAT YOU SAy")) {
    return ("PASS");
}
else{ return "FAIL";}
```

Output: ERROR

The error:

```
> ERROR:com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: TypeError: RegExp(...).text is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 1.97 seconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_32'
Session ID: 195d399d-c745-42c5-be6d-7d47811c9c26
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=20.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

Have I missed something?

Thanks I advance!

Comment: looks like it is this https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1666.

Comment: You may use  
    
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().toLowerCase().contains("what you say"); as workaround